# Worklight- Send application logs to specific log file

Tags: logging, websphere, ibm-mobilefirst

We have two hybrid applications running on our production server (App1-App2).

We define two levels of our logging :

`WL.Logger.debug`: Used to log the request and response of the applications if we need to track user interactions to debug any error which is logged to `trace.log`

`WL.Logger.error`: Used to log the error that could happen on our application which used to log to `SystemOut.log`

What is the configuration that we need to set to put a specific file logging for each application? and Is it applicable?

Like:

App1: `WL.Logger.debug >>>>>> App1_Debug.log`

```
`WL.Logger.error>>>>>> App1_Error.log`
```

And same for App2.

WL Version 6.2.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a Worklight perspective I can only say that Worklight does not, and cannot, provide you an ability to produce different files for logging. This is a feature (or maybe a nonexisting feature) of the underlying application server that you're using (WebSphere).