# Websphere Liberty - Custom Logging

Tags: logging, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, mobilefirst-adapters

We need to create a custom log file (Example: payment.log) that contains only a custom log for payment module.
We have already configured the server (server.xml) with below:

```
<logging consoleLogLevel="off" 
         copySystemStreams="false" 
         maxFiles="10"
         traceFileName="payment.log" 
         traceFormat="BASIC" 
         traceSpecification="com.dm.epay.logging.*=debug=enabled:com.worklight.*=off" 
         suppressSensitiveTrace="true"/>
```

Then, In the adapter (Example PaymentAdapter), we have called a custom java (DmEpayLogger) class: com.dm.epay.logging.DmEpayLogger.info("INFO >> Init Payment"); to write the log in "payment.log" file.

The problem is that **payment.log** file is mixed with other worklight logs. So, we believe that we have missed something in server.xml config file.

Any idea? Please advise!

Comment: Maybe this answer will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36041659/worklight-send-application-logs-to-specific-log-file/36041803#36041803 . I don't think you can write a specific adapter log to specific file.

Comment: what sort of trace statements do you see in your logs from Worklight?  Any idea what level of worklight logs is coming through? (info, finest, audit, etc)

Comment: SystemOut (O com.worklight.analytics.api.AnalyticsHttpService.sendDataToURL target server response code: 201...) 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet...
t.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation...

Answer (score 0):

What you've basically done in your server.xml setup is to replace the default messages.log file with a payments.xml file, but this only replaces the the file the logging will go to, that is all.

The ability to specify a log file to write to from adapters is not an available/built-in feature provided by IBM MobileFirst Platform.